# Как узнать, из какого сорса строка попадает в бинарь?

Tags: c++, linux, c, строки, безопасность

Можно ли как-то узнать, из какого файла (ещё лучше - строки файла) некоторые строки попали в бинарь? Имеются все сорсы и бинарь `test.so`, полученный из них. Для команды `strings test.so` выдаёт в одной из строк путь с sensitive инфой, которой не должно там быть. Хочу узнать, откуда эта строка приходит. Просто поиск по сорсам не находит эту строку, видимо макросом генерится.

Comment: @Harry говорю же, что простой поиск не находит. Видимо, этот путь генерится неким `__FILE__`, `assert` или другим препроцессингом. Причём просто `gcc -E` не помогает, т.к. много false positives в выдаче (видимо, из-за того, что эти же макросы используются в других местах или комментах, откуда потом удаляются при создании бинаря).

Comment: Это можно узнать из отладочной информации.

Comment: В выводе `gcc -E` не должно быть макросов. Попробуйте в выводе позатирать эти строки, а потом скомпилировать.

Comment: Без конкретности говорить о чем-то, мягко говоря, не результативно. Но обработанный препроцессором текст можно посмотреть? Наличие false positives уже дает вам информацию о том, как именно создается данный текст. В любом случае для более конкретного ответа нужна более конкретная информация...

Comment: objdump пробовали?

Comment: Перед компоновкой стоит проссмотреть все объектные файлы. Возможно, строка будет повторяться в нескольких из них

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать `gcc -E -P`, а не просто `gcc -E`.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

> -P
>
> Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor.
> This might be useful when running the preprocessor on something that
> is not C code, and will be sent to a program which might be confused
> by the linemarkers.